# How to use a dynamically created pattern as string in a replace using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a pattern that is a string dynamically created depending on an array. I believe I need to use a RegExp object to get this working, but it won't either. There are no errors in the console log, so the usage of the object is correct.

```
var pattern = "(?:\\()(iZeroPosSensor|iZeroPosSensorConnected)(?:\\))"   // does not work
//var pattern = /(?:\()(iZeroPosSensor|iZeroPosSensorConnected)(?:\))/ // works
var subst = "(<span class='observer'>$1</span>)"
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
```

I remember using RegExp with a string when doing a search, which worked.

**Edit:** added extra backslashes, still not working.

Comment: if you're using a string to supply your `RegExp`, you need to use a proper escaping. eg `/\d*/` becomes `'\\d*'`. It's different at strings ya know. There is a `\(` which should be `\\(`

Comment: it's supposed to work. check your code, maybe confused variables `pattern` and `regex`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$1` , use `$&` to insert matches.

Try the snippet

```js
var pattern = "(?:\()(iZeroPosSensor|iZeroPosSensorConnected)(?:\))" 
var subst = "(<span class='observer'>$&</span>)"
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

var text="SOMETHINGiZeroPosSensorTest";
console.log(text.replace(regex,subst));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) first param the `regex` and for the second parameter a function to format your string result:

```js
var pattern = /iZeroPosSensor(?:Connected)?/,
    regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g'),
    text ='Some demo string with iZeroPosSensor and iZeroPosSensorConnected for testing...',
    result = text.replace(regex, str => `(<span class="observer">${str}</span>)`);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this?

```js
var pattern = '(?:\\()(iZeroPosSensor(?:Connected)?)(?:\\))',
    regex = new RegExp( pattern, 'g' ),
    subst = "(<span class='observer'>$1</span>)",
    result = "(iZeroPosSensorConnected)".replace( regex, subst );

console.log(result);
```